# Scala typeclass without function argument

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, implicit

I'm currently working on my network library in scala. I encountered something like this:

```scala
object Packet {
  trait Reader[T] {
    def read(iterator: ByteIterator): T
  }

  object Reader {
    implicit object ByteReader extends Reader[Byte] {
      def read(iterator: ByteIterator): Boolean = iterator.getByte
    }
  }
}

class Packet {
  import Packet._

  def iterator: ByteIterator

  def read[T](implicit e: Reader[T]): T = {
    e.read[T]()
  }

  def readByte(): Byte = {
    this.read[Byte]()  // <- Unspecified value parameter e
  }
}
```

When I search the internet for answers, all of the examples I read was about function WITH arguments, not like me, my "read" function takes 0 argument. Is this the problem? How can I solve this?

I come from a C++ background, know the basic of Haskell, like the typeclass stuff. In C++, I can just do template specialization to make it work. In Haskell, `(read :: Byte)` will work. I tried to use reflection, but since packet read write is a very low level operation, reflection should be really bad for performance. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I don't see any compile failures there - the `unspecified` error you get is actually a runtime issue. That error simply means that your function `read` is unable to locate a proper `Reader` interface to use. Do this instead: At the site where you're invoking `readByte()`, import `Packet.Reader._` or do this in the `Packet` class.

Comment: @S.R.I I tried as you suggested, the error still exists.

Comment: Can you post the full, self-sufficient code?

Comment: @S.R.I Gist here: https://gist.github.com/CDR2003/7147f55c193e62c6994a

Comment: Try without the `()`, just `this.read[Byte]`. Also check that `implicitly[Reader[Byte]]` works, and that explicitly passing `ByteReader` works.

Comment: as @Imm said, you're bitten by the `()`. Removing that should work.

Comment: @S.R.I @Imm Yeah... I removed the `()` and it worked... This is really annoying behavior in scala. Thank you guys.

Comment: @PeterRen Generally speaking, you shouldn't have to worry about the distinction between parameterless and no-param methods. In this case, since you declared an implicit param in the function definition and then you invoke it with a no-param invocation, scala is confused into thinking that it doesn't have the full scope of declarations for running that function. If you remove that `()`, it takes the implicits into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend an empty parameter list:

```
def read[T]()(implicit e: Reader[T]): T =
  e.read(iterator)

def readByte(): Byte =
  this.read[Byte]()  // <- HURRAY IT WORKS
```

Removing the argument list (`()`) at the call site also works, but is typically frowned upon because syntactically argumentless calls are expected to be referentially transparent.